# Seeking appropriate CRS for Philippines while learning QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, philippines

What is the appropriate CRS for Philippines?

I'm trying to figure out what is the best CRS for Philippines while learning QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for CRS, I always use http://spatialreference.org/

If I was looking for local CRS for Philippines I would probably use something along [EPSG 4683](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4683/).